# how to take image magick mean result with vbs

Tags: vbscript, imagemagick

i'm making a program that identify blank images and moves a figured out the imagemagick command to know which pic is blank it worked fine in cmd showing the percentage of white pixels but with vbs a cant find out how to take the percentage from the command and put it in a variable

Comment: Could you maybe add some punctuation please?

Comment: Are you unable to find the method, or not understanding how to use it? Please show us the command that _is_ working, and the code that is _not_ working as expected.